# I will expand and create passive checks?

Tags: nagios

I have a running Ngios config and i will understanding, how works passive checks. I will expand and create my own passive checks.  At the moment on the nodes is running a cron-job (ioadm check) and the results are going to the hagios GUI. It works pretty good.

I want to understand how going the "ioadm check" results to Nagios? 
I hope you can help me.

regards
kinro

Comment: You have Ngios hagios and Nagios - are these typos or different? Please proof read before posting.

Comment: these are the typo. sorry.